# SQS queue parallel processing of messages using sqs-consumer nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

i tried using aws SQS for receiving messages from SQS in a batch of 5, and wanted to make 5 different child process so that each run simultaneously and when one of them finish the job it turns back to the parent process and then parent process can call another job from aws SQS . Similarly , this will make 5 jobs currently running on the server

The code written is :

```
const app = Consumer.create({
  queueUrl: 'QUEUE_URL',
  batchSize: 5,
  region:"eu-west-1",
  visibilityTimeout : 300,
  handleMessage: (message, done) => {

    for(var i in data.Messages)
    {
       console.log(JSON.parse(data.Messages[i].Body));
       done();       
    }
  },
  sqs: new AWS.SQS()

});

app.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(err.message);
});

app.start();
```

Here in the handleMessage() function how can multiple child process for each message can be created and then report back to one parent process  when one child process has finished the execution so that parent process can call for other message from the aws SQS ?

Thanks guys

Comment: What is your problem do you face here? or Are you checking whether proof of concept works or not?

Comment: i dont have idea to implement child and parent within the handleMessagefunction

Comment: Why limit yourself to just 5 at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would solve it in a scalable way,

```
Create a lambda to process each message.
Read Message from SQS and Call Lambda with Lambda API
```

Invoke Lamba from another Lambda/external Process:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property

Hope it helps.

Comment: i have used basically and ec2 server for polling and want to poll 5 messages at a time concurrently and one parent process creates different child process for parallel execution

Comment: You can do that with external process too. Lambda is serverless, ec2 will be server based.